# How to format the output of free/sar/such commands?

Tags: text-processing, memory, sar

I need to get some specific columns from the output of `free` command.

The way I'm following doesn't seem good, could anyone please suggest me a better way?

```
bash-3.2$ free -gotsi
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            56         29         27          0          0         29
Swap:           11          0         11
Total:          67         29         38
bash-3.2$

bash-3.2$ free -gotsi | cut -c-40,64-
             total       used       free    cached
Mem:            56         29         27        29
Swap:           11          0         11
Total:          67         29         38
```

Comment: depends what you want, can you give us specific values ad we can help

Comment: awk or perl might be nicer than cut in this case to operate on given columns/fields instead of characters.

Comment: I've tried awk, but the output of "free -gotsi | awk '{print $1"  "$2"  "$3"  "$4"  "$7}'" just doesn't look good! and is not even picking the last column

Comment: `free | sed -re 's/[ ]+/\t/g' | cut -f1-4,7` — the options to free do not work `o` excludes buffer and cache, `s` takes an argument, `i` is not an option (may be there are different versions).

Comment: that was actually 'free -g -o -t -si' -g to show in G's -o for old format, -t for total line and -si for 10's powers, I actually needed a neat output, which anyhow I couldn't get, Thanks though :)

Comment: On my system there is no `-si` there is an `--si` following the gnu standard for long options (to remove ambiguity). So you have to do `free -got --si` or `free -g -o -t --si` What OS are you using?

Comment: Linux 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5 #1 SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux, free version 3.2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want a better way to do it, based on columns not characters, if so:

```
free | #the option for free don't work for me
sed -re 's/[ ]+/\t/g' | #convert delimiter to single tab
cut -f1-4,7 # choose columns 1 2 3 4 7
```

Comment: That saved a lot of time, Thanks! just wondering about sed part.

Comment: the sed says: `-r` use extended regexp, `-e` here comes the expression, `s/[ ]+/\t/g` the expression ( `s` search and replace, `/` separator next is what to look for, `[ ]+` some spaces, `/` separator next is what to replace with, `\t` a tab character, `/` separator next is processing options, `g` global not just the first one on the line but all.).

Comment: that cleared all the doubts :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `cut` to get range of characters in this case. You want to get some specific column, so `perl` or `awk` is good tools to do this.

A `perl` example, print all column, except first column and first line:

```
$ free -got | perl -anle 'print "@F[1..$#F]" unless $. == 1'
5 4 1 0 0 1
0 0 0
6 4 2
```