# Output of sar is difficult to read

Tags: rhel, text-formatting, sar

I want to display statistics for devices. When I use `sar -d` I only see tens of devices with names that are hard to interpret:

```
Average:          DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
Average:      dev8-16      2.01      5.85    143.09     74.18      0.00      1.18      0.25      0.05
Average:       dev8-0      5.17     45.83    103.70     28.95      0.00      0.43      0.22      0.11
Average:      dev8-48      1.00     54.85     49.72    104.74      0.00      0.64      0.33      0.03
Average:      dev8-32      0.27      0.09      2.68     10.13      0.00      0.32      0.31      0.01
Average:     dev253-0      1.50     54.80     49.72     69.73      0.00      0.64      0.22      0.03
Average:     dev253-1      0.33      0.05      2.68      8.22      0.00      0.32      0.25      0.01
Average:     dev253-2      4.45      5.81    143.09     33.43      0.00      1.07      0.11      0.05
Average:     dev253-3      0.49      3.80      2.48     12.88      0.00      0.51      0.14      0.01
...
```

Adding `p` (making this `sar -dp`) provides me something I can mentally map to my mounted devices:

```
Average:          DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
Average:          sdb      2.01      5.85    143.09     74.18      0.00      1.18      0.25      0.05
Average:          sda      5.17     45.83    103.70     28.95      0.00      0.43      0.22      0.11
Average:          sdd      1.00     54.85     49.72    104.74      0.00      0.64      0.33      0.03
Average:          sdc      0.27      0.09      2.68     10.13      0.00      0.32      0.31      0.01
Average:    data2vg-data2vg--logslv      1.50     54.80     49.72     69.73      0.00      0.64      0.22      0.03
Average:    data1vg-foosumfnglv      0.33      0.05      2.68      8.22      0.00      0.32      0.25      0.01
Average:    data0vg-complv      4.45      5.81    143.09     33.43      0.00      1.07      0.11      0.05
Average:    rootvg-vloglv      0.49      3.80      2.48     12.88      0.00      0.51      0.14      0.01
Average:    rootvg-vlauditlv      0.78      5.01      6.80     15.19      0.00      0.37      0.19      0.01
...
```

But unfortunately the table layout gets messed up, which makes reading the data harder.
Can I somehow change the layout / table width ? I would prefer not having to parse the output and reformat it on my own, like described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141488/how-to-format-the-output-of-free-sar-such-commands).

If this matters: I am using RHEL 7.5

Comment: Tried piping to `column -t`?

Comment: No, to be honest I didn't even know that command ;-) It works, do you want to create an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the individual fields don't have spaces in them (which seems to be the case here), you can pipe to `column -t` to create a nice table of the output:

```
~ cat file | column -t
Average:  DEV                      tps   rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz  await  svctm  %util
Average:  sdb                      2.01  5.85      143.09    74.18     0.00      1.18   0.25   0.05
Average:  sda                      5.17  45.83     103.70    28.95     0.00      0.43   0.22   0.11
Average:  sdd                      1.00  54.85     49.72     104.74    0.00      0.64   0.33   0.03
Average:  sdc                      0.27  0.09      2.68      10.13     0.00      0.32   0.31   0.01
Average:  data2vg-data2vg--logslv  1.50  54.80     49.72     69.73     0.00      0.64   0.22   0.03
Average:  data1vg-foosumfnglv      0.33  0.05      2.68      8.22      0.00      0.32   0.25   0.01
Average:  data0vg-complv           4.45  5.81      143.09    33.43     0.00      1.07   0.11   0.05
Average:  rootvg-vloglv            0.49  3.80      2.48      12.88     0.00      0.51   0.14   0.01
Average:  rootvg-vlauditlv         0.78  5.01      6.80      15.19     0.00      0.37   0.19   0.01
```

However, `sar`'s output can have spaces in them. For example, on my system, I have  timestamps in the `sar` output, with spaces in them, and this breaks the output from `column -t`.

Comment: `column -t` might break other output of `sar`, but in my scenario this works perfectly fine. Thank you.